# Where are the reports submitted from system testing displayed?

Tags: 11.10, checkbox

With 11.10, I read  somewhere that a site where we can upload the system testing reports.
What is the URL of the site where I can refer the results uploaded by other users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The results are available from this website:

- http://friendly.ubuntu.com/